# URLSearchParams always returning empty

Tags: javascript

I need to make URLs like `example.com?want[]=1,2,3&want[]=1,2,3&want[]=1,2,3`

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();

for(let i in searchArr) {
    params.append('want[]', `${searchArr[i].id},${searchArr[i].quality},${searchArr[i].level}`);
}

console.log(params);
```

I've verified the given values exists, but it's always showing `URLSearchParams {}` with no values in console.

Why is it empty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

URLSearchParams is an object.  You need to cast it to a String using `toString()`, like so:

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('want[]', '1,2,3');
params.append('want[]', '1,2,3');
params.append('want[]', '1,2,3');

console.log(params.toString());
```

(Note: This will URL-encode characters like "[", "]", and ",")

Answer (score 1):

You can access values by using any of these methods available on URLSearchParams

- `getAll()`  -> For a specific search parameter
- `.entries()` -> For all key/value pairs
- `.values()`  -> For all the values

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('want[]', '1,2,3');
params.append('want[]', '1,2,3');
params.append('want[]', '1,2,3');

console.log(params.getAll('want[]'));
console.log([...params.entries()]);
console.log([...params.values()]);
```

Comment: You can even just do `[...params]`. Should be the same as `.entries()`